# How to show one De Morgan's Law implies the other (Set Theory)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, boolean-algebra

$1.)\space\space (A\space \cap B)' = A' \cup B'$

$2.)\space\space (A \cup B)' = A' \cap B'$

How can I show that $1 \rightarrow 2$? I understand how to get from the left side of each law to the right side, but not how to show that the first implies the second.

Comment: Hint: start with $(A \cup B)' = (A'' \cup B'')'$, then apply (1) in reverse to rewrite $(A'' \cup B'')$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying $1$ to $A'$ and $B',$ $$(A'\cap B')'=A''\cup B''=A\cup B$$
Thus we have, $$(A'\cap B')'=A\cup B.$$

Using the fact that two sets are equal if and only if their complements are equal we get,

$$(A'\cap B')''=(A\cup B)'.$$

Now, for all sets $P,$ we have $P''=P.$ Therefore,

$$A'\cap B'=(A\cup B)'$$

Comment: That was very helpful but somethings still not quite clicking for me. I understand $(A'\cap B')'=A''\cup B''=A\cup B$ but I'm not sure how that then implies $A'\cap B'=(A\cup B)'$

Comment: @drewdawg7 Just take complements on both sides. Use the fact that $A''=A.$

Comment: Wait, is there any difference between $A'\cup B'$ and $(A\cup B)'$? I think that's where I'm getting lost.

Comment: @drewdawg7 $(A' \cup B') \neq (A \cup B)'.$ I'll edit my answer for more clarity.

Comment: @drewdawg7 Maybe I can pin down your issue. From your first comment here, you seem to be having a problem with *transitivity*, i.e. going from the statement $x=y=z$ to $x = z$. Basically, transitivity states that if $x = y$ and $y = z$ (which is exactly what $x=y=z$ implies), then $x = z$. Simply put, just ignore the middle term and equate the two end terms. Maybe this will help you "get" my answer as well, which is essentially the same except that I wanted to avoid the double complement (but it seems you get this part).

Comment: @SahibaArora I traced through your edit on a piece of paper and it helped a lot, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'll introduce related boolean variables for clarity.

Let $A' = C,\ B' = D$. Note that $C' = A,\ D' = B$.

From the first one, taking the complement of both sides and reversing the sides, we get:

$(C \ \cup D)' = A \ \cap B = C' \ \cap D'$

So the first implies the second. The implication is reversible, and it's easy to show this by working on the second and going to the first.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I follow how that shows that $1\rightarrow2$

Comment: $C$ and $D$ are newly introduced "dummy" boolean variables. I've used $\space\space (A\space \cap B)' = A' \cup B'$ to show that $(C \ \cup D)' = C' \ \cap D'$. You can easily replace the $C$ and $D$ with $A$ and $B$ to get the exact same form as the second one, i.e. $\space\space (A \cup B)' = A' \cap B'$. It's basically the same idea as in Daniel's comment, except I introduced new variables to avoid the double complement for clarity.

Comment: you were right about me being stuck on the transitivity. I was overthinking too much, thank you for the help.